# where is homegroup password saved?

Tags: networking, command-line, homegroup

I was wondering where Windows saves the password of homegroups?

I usually connect or create several homegroups in many networks and every time I want to connect to one of these homegroups, windows remembers the password.
I want to know where ?

Also: how can I find out the password of joined homegroup from the command line?

Comment: Do you want a list of *all passwords* or do you want *the current homegroup's password*?

Comment: If i am connected to a homegroup , the password is shown in control panel or metro ... but where does windows keep all of them ? :D

Comment: [This](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/where-and-how-do-operating-systems-save-passwords-for-user-accounts) might be related.

Comment: I was hoping you'd say that! +1

Comment: Thanks , it Helped me to understand more of windows .Thanks ...
still looking for finding homegroup pass from cli though